# How to Search Array of Dictionary and show in UITableview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I am pretty new in IOS and I am using `UISearchDisplayController` for searching.

```
-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString
                               scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                                      objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar
                                                     selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

    return YES;
}

- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY SELF == %@", searchText];
    NSArray *filtered = [self.arrProductList filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    NSLog(@"%@", filtered);
}
```

And Here is my self.arrProductList is an array of array i.e

```
    ({
        ID = 1;
        description = "Coalesce Functioning on impatience T-Shirt";
        pname = "Coalesce Functioning T-Shirt";
        price = "299.00";
        qty = 99;
       },
    {
        ID = 2;
        description = "Eater Krylon Bombear Destroyed T-Shirt";
        pname = "Girl's T-Shirt";
        price = "499.00";
        qty = 99;
    },
    {
        ID = 3;
        description = "The Get-up Kids Band Camp Pullover Hoodie";
        pname = "Band Camp T-Shirt";
        price = "399.00";
        qty = 99;
    })
```

My question is **how to search using key "pname"**? My app is Crashed in

> filteredArrayUsingPredicate:

Comment: arrProductList is an array of dictionary ;-)

Comment: this is array of dictionary

Comment: oops sorry. I will Update my answer :).

Comment: Update your question with details about the crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My friend solve this issue. Here, is the code:

```
- (void) searchBarDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar*) lclSearchBar
{
    self.searchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;
}
#pragma mark - UISearchDisplayController delegate methods
-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{

    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString
                               scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                                      objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar
                                                     selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

    return YES;
}

- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    if (searchResults.count != 0) {
        [searchResults removeAllObjects];
    }
    for (int i=0; i< [self.arrProductList count]; i++)
    {
        NSString *string = [[self.arrProductList objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"pname"];
        NSRange rangeValue = [string rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        if (rangeValue.length > 0)
        {
            NSLog(@"string contains bla!");

            [searchResults addObject:[self.arrProductList objectAtIndex:i]];
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"string does not contain bla");
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"fiilterArray : %@",searchResults);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to modify your predicate to add the key to look for:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"pname == %@", searchText];
```

Additionally `==` will actually look for exact matches, ie if you'll enter `Band Camp T-Shirt` as search then you'll get the result, you won't be able to get any result if you simply enter `Band` or `Camp` or `Shirt`. So in order to achieve the character based search, you need to modify predicate to include `contain` keyword.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"pname contains[cd] %@", searchText];
```

`[cd]` will match with case insensitive.

Comment: thanks but my app crash in filteredArrayUsingPredicate:

Comment: Unless you paste the crash here, it is difficult to know the reason of your crash.

Comment: I change the code - (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    for (int i=0; i< [self.arrProductList count]; i++)
    {
        NSString *string = [[self.arrProductList objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"pname"];
        if ([string containsString:searchText])
        {
            NSLog(@"string contains bla!");
            
            [searchResults addObject:[self.arrProductList objectAtIndex:i]];
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"string does not contain bla");
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"fiilterArray : %@",searchResults);
}

Comment: but uilabel's value set to nil when reloading.

Comment: when you're using `NSPredicate`, then why you're searching data by `for` loop?

Comment: Because in  NSArray *filtered = [self.arrProductList filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]; line my app is crashed.

Comment: Then you need to check the cause of the crash, `NSPredicate` is way more faster than `for-each` in many cases. Paste the crash in your question so that we can know what error are you facing.