# search bar not responsive iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, uisearchbar, pfquery

I am very new to iOS development and building a self destructing iOS app with treehouse, we are using parse.com as a backend.

I have added a search bar to the app:-

```
- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {

    //dismiss keyboard and reload table
    [self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {

    //Enable the cancel button when the user touches the search field
    self.searchBar.showsCancelButton = TRUE;
}

- (void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {

    //disable the cancel button when the user ends editing
    self.searchBar.showsCancelButton = FALSE;
}

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {

    //dismiss keyboard
    [self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];

    //reset the foundUser property
    self.foundUser = nil;

    //Strip the whitespace off the end of the search text
    NSString *searchText = [self.searchBar.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];


    //Check to make sure the field isnt empty and Query parse for username in the text field
    if (![searchText isEqualToString:@""]) {

        PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
        [query whereKey:@"username" equalTo:searchText];
        [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {

                //check to make sure the query actually found a user
                if (objects.count > 0) {

                    //set your foundUser property to the user that was found by the query (we use last object since its an array)
                    self.foundUser = objects.lastObject;

                    //The query was succesful but returned no results. A user was not found, display error message
                } else {

                }

                //reload the tableView after the user searches
                [self.tableView reloadData];

            } else {

                //error occurred with query

            }

        }];

    }
}
```

when we search for a user we have to get the username exactly right including getting the uppercase/lowercase letter exactly right then press search for a user to display.

i want a user to display even if we do not get the upper/lowercase letters right so do a caseinsensitive search. also if the user does not get the usernames right can we offer users close to that username.

Comment: Check this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31339298/how-to-search-array-of-dictionary-and-show-in-uitableview. I hope this link is useful.

Comment: somewhat. thanks but i am not sure how to integrate it to get users from parse.com

Answer (score 1):

You should keep an all lowercase value for the username as a key for your PFUser class, or whatever class you are trying to query by username. When the search term is added to the PFQuery make sure it is all lowercase as well.

You can convert any string to become a lowercase string like this:

```
NSString* string = @"AAA";
NSString* lowerCaseString = string.lowercaseString;
```

So when you create the user you'd do something like this:

```
PFUser* user = [PFUser user];
user.username = self.usernameTextField.lowercaseString
...
```

And then when you want to query this user your query would look like

```
...
[query whereKey:@"username" containsString:searchString.lowercaseString];
...
```

Comment: ok but in the search bar when you type the first letter it is automatically uppercase until you deselect the shift button on keyboard, isn't there something i could add so that i can type the username uppercase or lowercase for the user to be found

Comment: check my edit to see how to convert a string to become a lowercase string

Comment: Will try it but is there no way we can search in upper/lower case so it can show users

Comment: they don't offer a case insensitive search